# Accepting and managing identical documents in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a tree structure with documents I'm indexing with Solr. Many documents exist in multiple places with identical content, but some metadata differs. I'd like to keep the duplicates in the index, so it is not de-duplication I'm looking for (or at least think so). What strategies are available to me, if I want to get single hits for the documents that are duplicated, but still being able to keep the individual documents available?

```
Folder A          |
  Folder A1       | 
    Document 1    | Category 1
    Document 2    | Category 1
  Folder A2       |
    Document 1    | Category 2
    Document 2    | Category 2
```

Document 1 is the same and exists in both Folder A1 and A2. When searching for something in Document 1, I want to be able to find it if I filter out Category 1 (or 2), but without filter, I'd like to get one hit, indicating that it matches multiple categories.

Is it better to approach this when populating the index, or when querying? What options are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good case for using [Collapse and Expanding](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/collapse-and-expand-results.html#collapse-and-expand-results).

You collapse the result set based on the Document ID of the document, allowing you to only get one result back for each distinct document. You're still able to get all variants of the unique document back (i.e. the different sets of metadata with their categories) by using the Expand functionality.

> `q=foo&fq={!collapse field=DocumentID}&expand=true`
>
> The `expand=true` parameter turns on the ExpandComponent. The ExpandComponent adds a new section to the search output labeled `expanded`.
>
> Inside the expanded section there is a map with each group head pointing to the expanded documents that are within the group. As applications iterate the main collapsed result set, they can access the expanded map to retrieve the expanded groups.

You also have the option of using [Result Grouping](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/result-grouping.html#result-grouping) but if you can make C&E work that's the recommended solution.